# How to change a users language from admin site in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-i18n

I'm implementing Django's I18N to translate a project and works really smooth. The thing is that I'm working on someone else's project and there was a field in the users profile named "language" which is a charfield which is filled with either "esp" or "eng". Therefore it was possible to change the any users language from the admin site.

**Is there a way to change any users language from the django admin site using Django's I18N?**

Note: I'm not trying to change the admin site language. Im trying to enter to the admin site being the user A and modify the user B to change the language user B sees the site.
In my setting I have the "es" and "en" language code available.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have on the user a language field that you can access like so request.user.language.

```
from django.utils import translation


class UserLanguageActivationMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        user = getattr(request, "user", None)
        if user:
            translation.activate(user, getattr(user, language, "Some meaning full default language"))

    return self.get_response(request)
```

Then add it to your middleware classes.